Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: sudo
When trying to remove openldap package that comes with rhel-8-baseos, it ends up giving an error saying "Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: sudo". Why is this base package bound to sudo? Can it be unbound and removed?
Never encountered while removing any baseos package.

The sudo package requires libldap.so.2 (for /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so, the default plugin), and libldap.so.2 is provided by the openldap package; so no, you can’t remove openldap.

Interesting. On my OEL 8 systems, ldd /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so does not list libldap.so as a dependency. However, dnf erase openldap also fails with message saying sudo is a protected package and cannot be removed.

That’s curious, presumably something else produces the dependency. I’ve verified my answer on RHEL and Rocky Linux (since those are the tags on the question), and /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so depends on libldap-2.4.so.2 on both distributions.
